# Ubuntu login takes 15 seconds, "I/O error dev fd0 sector 0"

Tags: ubuntu, login

After upgrading to Ubuntu 10.04, when I first login it takes 10+ seconds where it just sits at the gdm backgroup before taking me to gnome.  By switching to a terminal window during this 10 seconds I saw the error message

```
[   54.904480] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

being outputted.  I assume this has to do with the floppy drive... but I don't even have a floppy drive!  How do I disable this device and make this error message go away (and hopefully fix the long wait)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to your system as you would normally do. Press `alt+f2` . Type: `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` .

Here, you should see a line with `/dev/fd0` . Put a `#` to the beginning of that line, save the file, do a reboot.

For **example** it looks like this:
`/dev/fd0   /media/floppy0  auto    rw,users,noauto 0   0`

Make it look like **this**:
`#/dev/fd0  /media/floppy0  auto    rw,users,noauto 0   0`

---

Let's disable the floppy then. `Alt+f2` , `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` .

Start a new line with:
`blacklist floppy`

Reboot.

Comment: Hmm... Tried this, and restarted, still getting the same error message.  The problem is the error is happening with the device, not the mounting.

Comment: Just Blacklisting didn't work, but I did find this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/384579).  It had me do this `echo "blacklist floppy" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-floppy.conf && sudo rmmod floppy && sudo update-initramfs -u` which worked.  Thanks for your help troubleshooting this!

Comment: You can use `bootchart` to check what takes so much at boot also.

Answer (score 1):

I have been fideling and fooling around with that for yet rather a lang time.

A short and a long solution.

This is the short one:

- First see that your **fstab** file is okay, especially your **swap** partition.
- Than run:

**sudo update-initramfs -u**

and your problems should be over.

---+---

The long version written by someone else which I did not take note of. (Sorry people!)

Try:

Use blkid to determine the UUID of your swap partition, and while at it, make sure all other partitions have correct UUID's in /etc/fstab. Also can use lsblk -f to find the UUID's.

Put the correct UUID's into /etc/fstab, especially swap, for this error.

Put the correct UUID for swap into /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume.

Run sudo update-initramfs -u

Reboot. Fixed my triple boot of Stretch all with this error, as the swap file had changed.

---+---

The problem was due to my swap being encrypted. So the local-premount script in initramfs was waiting for a swap device that was not available, until it timed out. The relevant message was gave up waiting for suspend/resume device.

To disable this (as resuming from swap is not possible with an encrypted swap, and I don't use hibernation anyway), I modified this file: /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume.

In this file, a line with

RESUME=none
(instead of the UUID that was here) will disable waiting for a resume device.

Run

sudo update-initramfs -u
to apply the changes.

System now boots normally.

---+---

Bert.